# Using OpenArgs to pass multiple textboxs into a different form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to pass 3 textboxes into a different form via parsing the string. I am getting a run time error 13.

```
Private Sub txtFullName_Click()
    Const cstrForm As String = "frmInputInfo"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmInputInfo", acFormAdd, , , acDialog, _
        Me.txtFullName & "|" & Me.PATS_Job_Opening_ID & "|" & Me.NYCAPS_JobID
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    varSplitString = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")
    Me.[FullName].Value = varSplitString(0)
    Me.[PATS Job Opening ID].Value = varSplitString(1)
    Me.[NYCAPS_JobID].Value = varSplitString(2)
End Sub
```

and them on the form load I typed
    Any help will be appreciated

Comment: **On which line** do you get the error? ...and what is the rest of the error message? Do all three text boxes definitely have values? (and always will?)

Comment: @ashleedawg  The three text boxes that are opening in the new form are unbounded. Is that the reason for the error? and the rest of the error message says type mismatch. The error occurs on my Docmd line

Comment: While typing the code, _IntelliSense_ will show you the missing comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be extremely attentive with all those commas in the `DoCmd.OpenForm` options list.  It's just way too darn easy to cause a misalignment between what you and Access think about which values apply to which options.

In your case you intend to pass a string, `Me.txtFullName & "|" & Me.PATS_Job_Opening_ID & "|" & Me.NYCAPS_JobID`, to `OpenArgs`.  Unfortunately you omitted a comma, so Access thinks you're feeding it a value for `WindowMode`, which is supposed to be a number.  Therefore, error 13: *"type mismatch"*!

Do it this way and you eliminate any confusion about which value goes with which option.

```vba
Dim strArgs As String
strArgs = Me.txtFullName & "|" & Me.PATS_Job_Opening_ID & "|" & Me.NYCAPS_JobID
Debug.Print strArgs ' make sure you got what you expect '
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="frmInputInfo", _
    DataMode:=acFormAdd, _
    WindowMode:=acDialog, _
    OpenArgs:=strArgs
```

Also in the form event, make sure you got something for `OpenArgs` before you attempt to `Split` it.   As it stands now, if the form is ever opened without supplying `OpenArgs`, your code will essentially attempt `Split(Null, "|")` and that will trigger a different error.

You can test before split like this:

```vba
If Len(Me.OpenArgs) > 0 Then
   ' do your split thing here '
End If
```

Comment: Thank You , I could not understand my error but I caught it.